# Git https access broken on MacOS Sierra / SSL keychain error

Tags: git, ssl, curl, homebrew, keychain

after upgrading to MacOS Sierra my Git stopped working with https Repos like GitHub.

```
git clone https://github.com/monday-consulting/FSDevTools.git
Cloning into 'FSDevTools'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/monday-consulting/FSDevTools.git/': SSL: Can't find the certificate "My User" and its private key in the Keychain.
```

It seems like the access to the Keychain is broken (using `[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain`) as I can see the Certificate with it's private key in the keychain. In addition to that I've added it with `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

I've read about this here: https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/1105 but I'm not sure why there is a keychin access anyways?! 
My .gitconfig has no `[http]` section at all (with the `sslVerify` or `sslCert` properties) so I'm not using any Certificates at all.

The funny thing is - using SourceTree with the same Git executable and `"Allow SourceTree to modify my global Git and Mercurial config files"` disabled (so using the same .gitconfig) is working without problems.

I've also tried using curl from Homebrew and compiling Git with `--with-brewed-curl` - nothing changed.

Comment: Just wanted to let you guys know - I've built curl from the source (7.52.0-DEV) and it did not do the trick :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the environmental variable `GIT_SSL_CERT` being set. So Git always tried to use a certificate that was not needed.